# How I can replace with regex and vim?

Tags: regex, vim, replace, sed

I need to replace the next string with vim or sed:

```
[words with space and some caracter like _]
```

to

```
['words with space and some caracter like _']
```

only I need add ['foo'] used ' '

I am trying with this way in vim (but, doesn't work):

`:%s/[[a-z]\+]/'&'/g`

Answer (score 3):

Try this `:%s/\(\(\w\+\)\(\s\+\)\)\+_/'&'/gc`
**Explanation:** 
General syntax of the command is **:range s/pattern/string/gc**
**:** activates the command mode
**%** specifies the range and it means apply the command on the entire text of the file
**s** short for substitute
**Everything in between first and second / defines a pattern**
**\(** and **\)** are used to group parts of the pattern
**\w** is a meta character, which matches word character
**\+** is a quantifier, and matches 1 or more occurences
**\(\w\+\)** groups the above two parts of the pattern
**Everything between second and third / refers to the text that will replace the matched text**
**&** is a back reference, and it refers to the entire text matched by the pattern
**g** means replace all occurrences
**c** will prompt you to confirm each substitution
**\** is used to escape characters in **\w, \s, \+ \(, and \)**, which means that the character following \ has special meanings.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @BenjaminW. revised the answer and included explanation, hope it helps the community

Comment: How about `[foo]` and `[]`. Maybe you should also explain why to use backslashes.

Comment: @JairLopez added a line explaining the role of backslash

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the bracket meta-characters

```
:%s/[\[a-z\]\+]/'&'
```

In general, I find it helpful to make sure you're matching the right text visually, and then do the substitution

```
:set hlsearch
:set incsearch

# make sure your matching the right text
/text to match/

# paste from the register named "/" which holds the expression you just perfected
:%s/<control+r><slash>/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in vim

```
%s/\[\(.\{-}\)\]/\['\1'\]/g
```

Comment: You could use `[` and `]` without backslashes in `\['\1'\]`

Answer (score 0):

This works in `sed`. It's much like in `vim`.

```
sed "s/\[\([^]]*\)\]/['\1']/g" input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With the great [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin, it would be :

```
ysi[
```

Press `'`

Which literraly means :

- y "you"
- s "surround"
- i "inner"
- [ "bracket"

with `'`